# What is different between these words: métier, job, profession?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, synonymes

What is different between these words?

All of these words mean job in English but when to use them?

> - métier
> - job
> - profession

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if they might all be translated to *job* in English, they don't mean the same thing in French.

- *job* is used as *emploi* or *travail*. If you are unemployed and looking for a job, you can say *je cherche un emploi* or *je cherche un job* or *je cherche du travail*.
- *métier* is most of time what you learn. If you learned engineering in a school, you can say *j'ai appris le métier d'ingénieur*
- *profession* is the title or a group of *métier*. If you are a nurse, you can say *je travaille dans une profession médicale*. *profession* is closer (synonym) to *métier*.

Comment: Je serais curieux de connaître le genre de *job* tel que conféré par nos cousins d'outre-Atlantique. Pour avoir lu /entendu en plusieurs occasions ***ma / la** job*, je m'interroge.

Comment: Il semblerait que ce soit effectivement *une* job au Québec: https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/un-melange-de-genres/

Answer (score 2):

*Job* is the vulgar way to say *travail*. It's used most of the time for little job like summer work.
*Profession* is your job title (*boulanger*, *policier*, *journaliste*, ...). If *profession* is used for an individual, not for a work core capacity like *métier*

[métier](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/m%C3%A9tier/50997)
[job](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/job/44921)
[profession](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/profession/64156)

Comment: I disagree with the first sentence. *job* is not a way to say *métier*.

Comment: Laurent G yep, it's more "travail, sorry", I'll update

Comment: *Job* is not vulgar, it is colloquial.

Comment: @jlliagre The word *vulgar* here is meant, I presume, in its sense of "ordinary", as in, for example, *Vulgar Latin*; a usage nowadays, admittedly, quoted by dictionaries as dated.

Comment: @CarlMasens Yes, certainly what was meant although "dated" is an understatement.

Comment: If "Baptiste" = "Anna" then... I'll say : I agree! +1! ;-)